# Android - Cursor index out of bounds exception

Tags: android, sqlite, exception, indexing, cursor

My program is suppose to check the options table if it already set(inserted) an option(e.g. volume, vibration). Basically, if an option is not set, the first column at the table is 0. If the first row is empty, then switch to default option, else, switch to the option set. I surround my option checker with a try catch an receive this error:

> CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0.

I'm still newb to this sql stuff so I'm not sure if my codes are right to my needs.

This is my option checker at the OnCreate():

```
options = new DBFunctions(this);

    try{
    String row = "0".toString();
    long l = Long.parseLong(row);
    options.open();
    String retId = options.getId(l);
    int id = Integer.parseInt(retId);
    options.close();
    //codes for setting the options if/if no data in option table exists will be put here
    }catch(Exception e){
    String error = e.toString();
    tv.setText(error);
}
```

This is my getId() in my DBFunctions. java:

```
public String getId(long l) {

    String[] columns = new String[]{"id", "volume", "vibrate", "theme"};
    Cursor c = db.query(table, columns, "id=" + l, null, null, null, null);
    if(c !=null){
        c.moveToFirst();
        String id = c.getString(1);
        return id;
    }
    return null;
}
```

`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to get data from a `Cursor` that is empty(0 rows) and this throws that exception. I saw your other questions and I've seen that your `id` column in the `options` table is set as `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT`. **AUTOINCREMENT** means that this column will increment its value each time a row is inserted in the database and I think it is also starting at a value above 0(not sure). This means that the query you make in the `getId` method will always return an empty `Cursor`(you query for the rows with `id` 0 but there are none in the database).

I didn't understand the first part of your question the one with inserted/not inserted in the database and switching to defaults so I can say how to do what you want.

Here is some sample code with `SharedPreferences`:

```
// When you want to check the status of the options
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this); //in an activity
    // volumeStatus, vibrateStatus and themeStatus represent the current status of the options
boolean volumeStatus = prefs.getBoolean("volume_key", false); // if volumeStatus is false it is the first app run or the user put the volume to off
boolean vibrateStatus = prefs.getBoolean("vibrate_key", false); // the same as for volumestatus
String themeStatus = prefs.getString("theme_key", null); // if themeStatus is null it is the first run of the app or the user didn't choose a theme

    // when the user modifies one of the preferences use this
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("volume_key", true); // the use sets the volume to on like in the database
            editor.commit();
```

Comment: Thanks for checking up on my other questions.. :) I already tried creating a button for showing values and it display all the data I inputted, which means my insert code is correct. Then I tried my value checker(my code above), it still displays the error. I also tried changing the row I am looking for(previous is 0) to 1, still display the error..

Comment: @PhilipSy Check your data and put an id that you do have in your database and use that to query. The problem is that I don't understand what you are trying to do: the user inserts settings in the database(only one, many etc?!?) but if the first row is empty(?!?) switch to the defaults?!?

Comment: "I didn't understand the first part of your question the one with inserted/not inserted in the database and switching to defaults so I can say how to do what you want." - What I mean is, if you use the app the first time, it will set the default options (Vibrations-On, Volume-On, etc.). If you set your options, it will check if you already set it before. If it detects that option table has a value, it will only update your option, else if no value, it will insert. Basically, my option table should consist of 1 row only..

Comment: @PhilipSy If that is what you want why do you want to use a database when you have the `SharedPreferences` that are special designed for this kind of cases?

Comment: You mean it is like a database but without the sql stuff? Thanks! I will try your codes and research on it.. :)

Comment: @PhilipSy There is no need for a database when all you want to store are 2 boolean values and one `String`. The `SharedPreferences` is much easier to work with for this case.

Comment: It worked like a charm! Thank you very much! Unfortunately, I don't have enough rep pts. to upvote..